# Swiperjs issue with pictures

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I'm attempting to develop a new version of my website with a large picture slider, using [**SwiperJS**](https://swiperjs.com/). Unfortunately, I've encountered an issue while working with the images in this slider.
As you can observe on [**this CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Alan-Renault-the-selector/pen/rNPbQew), I'm struggling to display my images side by side with only the gutter space in between.
Instead, there's always a large space after each photo, highlighted with an orange background.

Here is the code snippet for the slider in my website :

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: "auto",
    spaceBetween: 30,
    grabCursor: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
  });
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    background-color: blue;
}

.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 94vh;
    max-height: 1400px;
}

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: orange;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Photographies - Alan Renault</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11.0.5/swiper-bundle.min.css " rel="stylesheet">     
    

</head>
    <body>
    
            <div class="content">

                <!-- Slider main container -->
                <div class="swiper mySwiper">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_9386.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_8940.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_8888.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_7940.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_7317.jpg"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                </div>
      
            </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the result I try to achieve :
[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gojf.jpg)

Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help.

I've tried manipulating the `.swiper-slide class` in the CSS, but it consistently results in a malfunctioning slider.

Comment: Proper [mre] of the issue belongs directly inside the question, please do not just send us to external platforms.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be easier to understand the complete code in action along with its output. I've edited my post with the code snippets that seem to be causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play wit `height`, `slidesPerViev`, etc. and adjust how you need.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: "1.5",
    spaceBetween: 20,
    grabCursor: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
  });
```

```css
* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        }

        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .content {
            background-color: white;
        }

        swiper {
            width: 100%;
            height: 60vh;
            max-height: 1400px;
        }

        .swiper-slide {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            background: #fff;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: white;
           
        }

        .swiper-slide img {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
```

```html
<link href=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11.0.5/swiper-bundle.min.css " rel="stylesheet"> 
<div class="content">

                <!-- Slider main container -->
                <div class="swiper mySwiper">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_9386.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_8940.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_8888.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_7940.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://alanrenault.com/gallery/photographies/ALR_7317.jpg"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                </div>
      
            </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

because the .swiper container has no set width. And as a result the slide is taking the whole width of the parent-container.

If you for example set the width of `.swiper` to `100vw` and change `slidesPerView: "auto",` to `slidesPerView: 2,` you will see something more like your design.

Please also note that it is always easier to answer your questions with code directly in your question, as a working snippet for example. Hope this helped